# How do i sum data from 2 tables left joined to 1 table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

When I comment out all lines pertaining to either the "Sales Line" or "Warehouse Entry" table the query works as expected. But when I use this query as is; it returns faulty(unrealistically high by at least 5 digits) data.

The idea is to iterate the "Item" table and to obtain the amount in stock as well as the sum of quantity sold as well as It's worth. I think there must be something wrong by the way I'm joining these tables. Both "Warehouse Entry" and "Sales Line" table have multiple entries that can be linked to `I.[No_]`.

```
USE NAV2009_R2_SHOWTEX_LIVE

SELECT I.[No_]
    ,sum(S.[Quantity (Base)]) AS [Quantity Sold]
    ,min(I.[IP Total (Manual)]) * sum(WE.[Quantity]) AS [Stock Value]
    ,sum(WE.[Quantity]) AS [Quantity Stock]
FROM [Item] AS I
INNER JOIN [Warehouse Entry] AS WE ON WE.[Item No_] = I.[No_]
    AND WE.[Location Code] = 'BU'
    AND WE.[Bin Code] <> 'SHIPPING'
    AND WE.[Bin Code] <> 'WORKSHOP'
    AND WE.[Bin Code] <> 'OUTBOX'
    AND WE.[Bin Code] <> 'CUT'
    AND WE.[Bin Code] <> 'VERZEND'
INNER JOIN [Sales Line] AS S ON S.[No_] = I.[No_]
    AND S.[Shipment Date] > '07/01/2015'
    AND S.[Document Type] = 1
WHERE I.[No_] LIKE '140003000007'
GROUP BY I.[No_]
```

Sample Data

**No.|Quantity Sold|Stock Value|Quantity Stock**

Wrong Data

```
140003000007|204484537.36000000000000000000|13051602.124400|    2355884.86000000000000000000
```

Right Data

```
140003000007|61703.24000000000000000000|13623.801800|2459.17000000000000000000
```

Comment: Move WE and S conditions to ON clauses, to get true left join behavior.

Comment: @jarlh , thanks but the numbers are still incorrect. I'll edit my code

Comment: can you post sample data and expect result ?

Comment: Replace left join by inner join and delete the "... is not null ..." line

Comment: thanks, but still wrong :/

Comment: How about placing your query in a CTE as seen here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

And do the sum aggregate on the desired field from the CTE instead?

If your query returns all of the correct rows, the sum of the column should not have any issues

Comment: Remove agregate functions and "Group by" to display all rows and to understand why they are too numerous. I think you miss a condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  sumQuantityBase as [Quantity Sold],
        minIP * sumQuantityBase as [Stock Value],
        sumQuantityBase as [Quantity Stock]
FROM
    (SELECT MIN(I.[IP Total (Manual)] )as minIP,
            No_
     FROM I 
     WHERE [No_] like '140003000007'
     GROUP BY No_) MinI INNER JOIN
    (SELECT SUM([Quantity]) as sumQuantity,
            [Item No_]
     FROM WE 
    WHERE [Location Code] = 'BU' 
      AND [Bin Code] <> 'SHIPPING'  
      AND [Bin Code] <> 'WORKSHOP' 
      AND [Bin Code] <> 'OUTBOX'  
      AND [Bin Code] <> 'CUT' 
      AND [Bin Code] <> 'VERZEND'    
      GROUP BY [Item No_] ) SumWE
  ON MinI.[No_]  = SumWE[Item No_] INNER JOIN
  (SELECT SUM([Quantity (Base)]) as sumQuantityBase,
          No_
   FROM S 
   WHERE [Shipment Date] > '07/01/2015' 
     AND [Shipment Date] IS NOT NULL  
     AND [Document Type] = 1 
  GROUP BY No_ ) SumS
 ON SumS.[No_] = MinI.[No_]
```

Try this one. When you want to aggregate data using sum or min function i'd recommend you do it in a subset. that way you keep it simple

Comment: Ouch - so many nested queries. Can't be good if the query has to be rerun a multitude of times

Comment: no it is good. every single subset returns only the results needed since the where clauses are defined only in the subsets. There is just 1 level level of nesting and anyway it should'nt be scaring you.

Comment: Thank you @Sapi, You're query worked, I had to change a few things here and there, but by the speed you wrote it and the amount of time that would have taken me, I'm not about to look a gift horse in the mouth . :)

Comment: The query is blazing fast in any case